# Watch channel in rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, watch, rust-tokio

I need help in understanding borrow() and borrow_and_update() both looking similar to me.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    use tokio::sync::watch;
    use tokio::time::{Duration, sleep};

    let (tx, mut rx) = watch::channel("hello");
    let mut rx2 = tx.subscribe();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            println!("{}! ", *rx2.borrow_and_update());
            if rx.changed().await.is_err() {
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    tx.send("world").unwrap();
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
}
```

this is the example that I am using and I can't see any difference while using `borrow()` and `borrow_and_update()`.
I have read the docs which say `borrow_and_seen()` will mark the value as seen while `borrow` doesn't.
can anyone help me understanding these two by giving a suitable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [dedicated section in the documentation on when to use which](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/index.html#borrow_and_update-versus-borrow):

> ### `borrow_and_update` versus `borrow`
>
> If the receiver intends to await notifications from [`changed`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.changed) in a loop,
> [`Receiver::borrow_and_update()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.borrow_and_update) should be preferred over
> [`Receiver::borrow()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.borrow).  This avoids a potential race where a new value is
> sent between [`changed`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.changed) being ready and the value being read. (If
> [`Receiver::borrow()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.borrow) is used, the loop may run twice with the same value.)
>
> If the receiver is only interested in the current value, and does not intend
> to wait for changes, then [`Receiver::borrow()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.borrow) can be used. It may be more
> convenient to use [`borrow`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.borrow) since it's an `&self`
> method—[`borrow_and_update`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/struct.Receiver.html#method.borrow_and_update) requires `&mut self`.

Giving an example that consistently reproduces the loop running twice is hard because it relies on consistently hitting the race condition.